# Promise.all ignores one promise and calls another one twice

Tags: javascript, promise

Im trying to use Promise.all to run a couple of network calls and then tell me when they've all completed. In my example I have three promises. The promises are returned from different objects, but two of them have the same method signature. The first promise is never ran, but the second promise is called twice. It works if I change the name of one of the methods, but the number of parameters doesn't seem to matter. Code example:

```js
const test = {};

test.ObjectOne = () => {
  aMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method one");
  });
  
  bMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method one two");
  });

  return this;
};

test.ObjectTwo = () => {
  aMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method two");
  });

  return this;
};

const objectOne = test.ObjectOne();
const objectTwo = test.ObjectTwo();

Promise.all([
  objectOne.aMethod(1, 2),
  objectOne.bMethod(1, 3),
  objectTwo.aMethod(1, 2),
]).then((responses) => {
  console.log(responses);
});
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
["Method one", "Method one two", "Method two"]
```

But the actual output is:

```
["Method two", "Method one two", "Method two"]
```

What is the issue that Im seeing?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining your objects correctly. This:

```
test.ObjectTwo = () => {
  aMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method two");
  });

  return this;
};
```

creates a global variable `aMethod` (this overwriting the previously defined `aMethod`) and returns the global object (`window`).

This is how this could be done:

```js
const test = {};

test.ObjectOne = () => ({
    aMethod: (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("Method one");
    }),
    bMethod: (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("Method one two");
    })
});

test.ObjectTwo = () => ({
    aMethod: (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("Method two");
    })
});

const objectOne = test.ObjectOne();
const objectTwo = test.ObjectTwo();

Promise.all([
    objectOne.aMethod(1, 2),
    objectOne.bMethod(1, 3),
    objectTwo.aMethod(1, 2),
]).then((responses) => {
    console.log(responses);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can invoke the specific function by calling the promise method along to not overwrite the aMethod functions

```js
const test = {};

test.ObjectOne = () => {
  aMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method one");
  });
  
  bMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method one two");
  });

  return this;
};

test.ObjectTwo = () => {
  aMethod = (paramOne, paramTwo) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Method two");
  });

  return this;
};

const objectOne = test.ObjectOne;
const objectTwo = test.ObjectTwo;

Promise.all([
  objectOne().aMethod(1, 2),
  objectOne().bMethod(1, 3),
  objectTwo().aMethod(1, 2),
]).then((responses) => {
  console.log(responses);
});
```